# How can I use for loop to build a dictionary that can reads values from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first number is the student id, the second is the code of the course.

```py
course = ["001, aly6015", "002, aly6050", "001, aly6020", "003, aly6070", "001, aly6140"]

dict = {}

for i in course:
```

I want to build a dictionary like the following:
when I input `dict['001']`
then the output comes as `aly6015, aly6020, aly6140`

I don't know how to read value from the course list so that I can append 001, 002, 003 as keys in my dictionary and course code as values in my dictionary.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since the elements of the list are strings, did you try splitting the strings (`i.split(", ")`)?

Comment: This is not valid python code - why are there `.` on the line ends?

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in course:
    sid, cid = item.split(', ')
    d[sid].append(cid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
courses = ["001, aly6015", "002, aly6050", "001, aly6020", "003, aly6070", "001, aly6140"]
d = {}
for course in courses:
    key, value = course.split(",")
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(value)
    else:
        d[key] = [value]
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'001': [' aly6015', ' aly6020', ' aly6140'], '002': [' aly6050'], '003': [' aly6070']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split each course on `", "`, then group with [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
courses = ["001, aly6015", "002, aly6050", "001, aly6020", "003, aly6070", "001, aly6140"]

d = {}
for course in courses:
    student_id, course_code = course.split(", ")
    d.setdefault(student_id, []).append(course_code)

print(d)
# {'001': ['aly6015', 'aly6020', 'aly6140'], '002': ['aly6050'], '003': ['aly6070']}
```

But its probably nicer to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), as shown by [@Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160295/how-can-i-use-for-loop-to-build-a-dictionary-that-can-reads-values-from-a-list/61160412#61160412)

Its also not a good idea to use `dict` as a variable name, as it shadows the builtin function [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)